# How to retrieve all indexes from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

How to retrieve all indexes from pandas 0.10.1 DataFrame?

I've tried to find in documentation and on the web, and still after at least half a hour without any result.

Thanks,
Slava

Comment: try: df.index, df.columns, new user docs at: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/10min.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Jeff mentioned you will find this info in the [official docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/10min.html#viewing-data). Example:

```
>>> df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2), index = list('abc'), columns=list('df'))
>>> df
     d           f
a    0.629197    0.921025
b    0.534993    0.018760
c    0.156801    0.298251
```

Index:

```
>>> df.index
Index([a, b, c], dtype=object)
```

Columns:

```
>>> df.columns
Index([d, f], dtype=object)
```